# Command to clean screen in PyScripter?

Tags: python, pyscripter

Is there a single command to clean the screen of the Python Interpreter every time one runs a code in PyScripter?

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto pyscripter menus and check the box for clear output before run.
Tools>Options > IDE options > Python interpreter > Clear output before run.

Very useful in interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os #top of script`
os.system('cls') #call whenever you want to clear terminal
```

Comment: If this is how it works on pyscripter, I would recommend using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess) package instead of `os.system`

Comment: I pasted the lines on the first line of the script, but it doesn't work. I might be doing sthg wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
```

or as suggested by jadkik94:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear', shell=True)
```

**UPDATE**

I now understand that you are trying to clear the interpreter screen in the IDE application "PyScripter". I don't have any experience with this IDE, but usually IDE's are meant for developing and not for actual deployment, so if this is part of the application, and you ant to see that it's running correctly, you should run it in a command/console window and use the methods I posted here by me and others.

If you just want to create a "clean" window, but don't mind if it's actually cleared the console or not you can do something like this:

```
print "\n" * 100
```